# How to find out which function is called when it is bound to an event with jquery?

Tags: javascript

For example on [this website](http://seniorzynaczasie.pl/kategoria/hobby/), how do I find out what code is responsible for smooth scrolling? Setting a breakpoint on "scroll" event just shows jQuery.

Comment: Perhaps this code will help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

I see some calls to .animate() and .scrollTop() in your site.js file.  I would look there.  They are part of jquery, so that explains your breakpoint.